# flex-grow not working in column layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, flex-grow

I am trying to have the `views-cntnr` take up any space not used by `views-cntnr` and `menubar` divs. To achieve this, I have a flex display set to column direction. Then I set the `flex-grow` property for the `views-cntnr` to 1. Doesn't appear to be doing anything. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74g987qn/4/)

NOTE: Not sure if this matters but I have some nested flex displays going on.

### HTML

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<section class="analysis">
  <div class="menubar">
    <div class="view-ctrls text-center">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'active-view': active_views[0]}" ng-click="toggleView(0)">R-Theta</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'active-view': active_views[1]}" ng-click="toggleView(1)">Cartesian</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'active-view': active_views[2]}" ng-click="toggleView(2)">Longitudinal</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'active-view': active_views[3]}" ng-click="">Console</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="views-cntnr">
    <div class="r1">
      <div id="v1" class="view">V1</div>
      <div id="v2" class="view">V2</div>
      <div id="v3" class="view">V3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="r2">
      <div id="v4" class="view">V4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="frame-ctrl-cntnr">
    <div id="frame-num" class="frame-ctrl"># X</div>
    <div id="frame-range-cntnr" class="frame-ctrl">
      <input type="range">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

### CSS

```
.analysis {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


/* MENUBAR */

.menubar {
  padding: 4px 0 4px;
  background-color: #eee;
}


/* menubar */


/* VIEWS */

#views-cntnr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}


/* ROW 1 */

.r1 {
  display: flex;
}

.r1 .view {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: black 1px solid;
  border-right: none;
}

.r1 .view:last-child {
  border-right: black 1px solid;
}
/* row 1 */

/* ROW 2 */
.r2 .view {
  border: black 1px solid;
  border-top: none;
}


/* row 2 */


/* views */


/* FRAME CTRL */

#frame-ctrl-cntnr {
  display: flex;
}

.frame-ctrl {
  border: black 1px solid;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
}

.frame-ctrl:last-child {
  border-right: black 1px solid;
}

#frame-num {
 width: 50px;
}

#frame-range-cntnr {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 4px;
}

/* frame ctrl */
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Everything in your code is working fine.

The only issue is that ***your flex container has no specified height***. Therefore, the height resolves to `auto`, meaning the height of the content.

The `flex-grow` property distributes *free* space in the container. With no free space in your container, `flex-grow` has nothing to do.

Try this adjustment to your CSS:

```
.analysis {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

This tells the flex container to be the height of the viewport. Now the height of the container is taller than the height of the content, and you will notice `flex-grow` doing its work.

[Revised Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74g987qn/5/)

[Learn more about the `height: auto` default on most elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46546152/3597276).

Comment: I am curious why `height: 100%;` not working. When I use `100vh` like your solution, it works..

Comment: because height: 100%; means 100% of parent height and by default it will give you 0

Comment: @AllanRuin, explained here: [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)