# Justify-content won't work with align-items in CSS Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, display

I am playing with Flexbox for the first time and I wonder why doesn't the property align-items: flex-end work with justify-content: center. I tried changing as well to other values rather than flex-end but still nothing would move around the cross axis.

Here is my HTML/CSS Code. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Playing with CSS Flexbox</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--
        <nav id="logo">
            <p class="logotext">Welcome There!!</p>
        </nav>
        -->
        <main id="container">
            <section class="box red-box">
                 <!--
                 <img src="images/Chilli-medium.jpg" alt="chilli" class="first-image">
                    -->
            </section>
            <section class="box green-box">
            </section>
            <section class="box blue-box">
            </section>
            <section class="box violet-box">
            </section>
            <section class="box black-box">
            </section>
            <section class="box yellow-box">
            </section>
            <section class="box grey-box">
    </body>
</html>

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: white;

}


#container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: flex-end;


}

.box {
    padding: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 50vh;
    width: 5vw;

}

.red-box {
    background-color: indianred;

}

.green-box {
    background-color: green;


}

.blue-box {
    background-color: blue;

}

.violet-box {
    background-color: rebeccapurple;


}

.black-box {
    background-color: black;
}

.yellow-box {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.grey-box {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: Found it: I set the height of the main container to 100vh and now it is working fine :)

Comment: Yes, the flex container needs to have height: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35259772/3597276